# ASP.net Identity can't login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm using Asp.net Identity and I've deployed my web role to Azure, and changed my connection string in Web.config so it looks like this:

```
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=SERVERNAME,1433;Database=DATABASE;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I haven't changed default Account controller, but when I try to Login nothing nothing happens except that URL changes to "/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FRoutines" which should happen if user successfully logged in (no errors are shown)

Why is this happening ? (and how can I fix it)

**EDIT**

Here is code which configures ASP.net Identity

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public DatabaseContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

        }
     }


  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .ToTable("Users");

        var usermapping = new UserMapping();
        usermapping.MapUser(modelBuilder);
    }
```

I've noticed that now even when I'm using LocalDb I can't Log in, and I don't know why is this because, I haven't changed my code, only changes that I made to the project is Added Azure web service, and Asp.net web Api 2 project (and when I've tested locally I didn't run my web api project), before this everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what I exactly happened, but I've fetched older version of solution from TFS and that helped (eve though code was same)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your connection is really used when you deploy (in Web.config.release)?
In case you are, try testing the website locally (with the Azure SQL connection string) and stepping through the code for POST version of Login. There you should be able to see, what exactly is going on. You will probably need to enable access to SQL from your IP address, which is easy to do - just go to Azure Portal, click on your SQL database and down below select Manage, which will automatically ask you for your IP address access permission.

Comment: I've checked release version and it's there, also my IP is in list of allowed IPs, and I've debugged Log in part of code, and everything was fine, but for some reason I'm still not logged in

Comment: How are you determining that you are "not logged in".  Is this an issue with a different part of your app?

Comment: Well, when I go to some part of app where I have to be logged in, in order to see it (I use [Authorize] attribute) I'm redirected to /Account/Login, then I log in again, but nothing happens